# for loop with if else statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I know lots of people have posted about this, and I did look through the answers to write my code, but it's still not working... Can someone point out where i'm doing wrong please? many thanks in advance!

```
for(j in 1:1000){

        for(i in 1:52){

                   if (i == 1){
                        r.sims[i,] <- r.sims[1]
                        }
                 else if (i == 2){
                       r.sims[i,] <- r.sims[2]
                       }
                 else (i > 2){
                               r.sims[i,] <- r.sims[i-1,]*ar1 + r.sims[i-2,]*ar2 + e.sims[i,] + e.sims[i-1,]*ma1
                           }

                       }

                }
```

i have the following errors

```
Error: unexpected '{' in:
"       }
             else (i > 2){"
>                                r.sims[i,] <- r.sims[i-1,]*ar1 + r.sims[i-2,]*ar2 + e.sims[i,] + e.sims[i-1,]*ma1
Error in r.sims[i, ] <- r.sims[i - 1, ] * ar1 + r.sims[i - 2, ] * ar2 +  : 
  replacement has length zero
>                    }
Error: unexpected '}' in "                   }"
>                    
>                        }
Error: unexpected '}' in "                       }"
> 
>                 }
Error: unexpected '}' in "                }"
>
```

Comment: I've never worked with R, but I've also never seen an `else` statement with a conditional ... shouldn't it be an `else if`?

Comment: The error message helpfully points out that `else (i > 2){` is a syntax error. However, your main problem is that you use a `for` loop for this. R is not C. It seems like you could just use the `filter` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without understanding what your code is supposed to do, I have nevertheless made an example of how you might fix your script. I think the key is that you need to supply curly brackets `{...}` following your `else` statement in order for it to consider the following code.

#### Example:

```
r.sims <- matrix(runif(52)*100, nrow=52, ncol=100)
e.sims <- matrix(runif(52)*100, nrow=52, ncol=100)

ma1 <- 1
ar1 <- 2
ar2 <- 3

for(j in 1:1000) {
    for(i in 1:52) {
        if (i == 1) {
            r.sims[i,] <- r.sims[1]
        } else {
            if(i == 2) {
                r.sims[i,] <- r.sims[2]
            } else {
                if(i > 2) {
                    r.sims[i,] <- r.sims[i-1,]*ar1 + r.sims[i-2,]*ar2 + e.sims[i,] + e.sims[i-1,]*ma1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand the concept of `else`.

`else` covers all cases that didn't match previous `if` or `else if` statements.
Therefore, you cannot specify any condition for `else`.

To cover all cases where `i` is not `1` or `2` simply use `else`, without any `()` brackets.

If you want to have a condition, use `else if (condition)`.